# Gdx.audio error

Tags: java, audio

So i'm doing the simple game thing in the libgdx wiki and i have finished them and i get these error.

First is this :

`dropSound = new Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("drop.wav"));`

`rainMusic = new Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("rain.mp3"));`

i get the error in Gdx.audio

And the second is this

```
Iterator<Rectangle> iter = raindrops.iterator();
```

the error is in Iterator

That's what i see in the console

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
Gdx.audio cannot be resolved to a type
Gdx.audio cannot be resolved to a type

at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
Gdx.audio cannot be resolved to a type
Gdx.audio cannot be resolved to a type

at com.JohnAilamakis.Drop.Drop.create(Drop.java:55)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:136)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
```

Please if you can tell me whhat's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this error, reference gdx.jar in the project where ApplicationListener cannot be resolved. Sometimes it's also a problem with Eclipse and deleting and re-importing the project can help to solve the error.

Comment: if i delete and re-import my work wont be lost right?Also can you please tell me a how to do that?Sry im just new :c Also how can i fix the Iterator thing?